# Consuming CXF Web Service from HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, cxf

I am trying to create one CXF web service consumer which will be a simple HTML page.

I am able to create javascript client code from wsdl file using wsdl2js utility but not able to understand how to link up that with my HTML page.

How can we link up that code with HTML page or any other way to call web service method using simple javascript call?

Thanks in advance